# PyQt5: как открыть второе окно при нажатии кнопки?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть код, не могу реализовать, чтоб по нажатию кнопки вылезало новое окно, и там были еще 2 кнопки(см воторой код).Размеры окна, кнопок, их названия надо оставить такими же.

**Вот первый код:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow


class Guitar(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
super().__init__()
self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
self.setGeometry(250, 55, 1200, 800)
self.setWindowTitle('Гитара')

self.First_button = QPushButton('Первая струна(клавиша 1)', self)
self.First_button.resize(170, 50)
self.First_button.move(40, 100)

self.Second_button = QPushButton('Вторая струна(клавиша 2)', self)
self.Second_button.resize(170, 50)
self.Second_button.move(40, 200)

self.Accords_button = QPushButton('список аккордов', self)
self.Accords_button.resize(200, 100)
self.Accords_button.move(300, 500)

self.Songs_button = QPushButton('список песен', self)
self.Songs_button.resize(200, 100)
self.Songs_button.move(300, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Guitar()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Вот второй код:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow


class Guitar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(250, 55, 1200, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Гитара')

        self.First_button = QPushButton('Первая струна(клавиша 1)', self)
        self.First_button.resize(170, 50)
        self.First_button.move(40, 100)

        self.Second_button = QPushButton('Вторая струна(клавиша 2)', self)
        self.Second_button.resize(170, 50)
        self.Second_button.move(40, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Guitar()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если второй код у вас является отдельным файлом, то вам нужно сначала переименовать название его класса, чтобы не было конфликта с классом `Guitar` из первого кода.
2. Затем импортируем второй код и его класс: `from second_form import Guitar_2`
3. Затем добавим, например, кнопке `First_button` функцию открытия второго окна:

   `self.First_button.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)`

---

### В итоге получаем **первый код:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication
from second_form import Guitar_2

class Guitar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setGeometry(250, 55, 1200, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Гитара')

        self.First_button = QPushButton('Первая струна(клавиша 1)', self)
        self.First_button.resize(170, 50)
        self.First_button.move(40, 100)
        self.First_button.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)

        self.Second_button = QPushButton('Вторая струна(клавиша 2)', self)
        self.Second_button.resize(170, 50)
        self.Second_button.move(40, 200)

        self.Accords_button = QPushButton('список аккордов', self)
        self.Accords_button.resize(200, 100)
        self.Accords_button.move(300, 500)

        self.Songs_button = QPushButton('список песен', self)
        self.Songs_button.resize(200, 100)
        self.Songs_button.move(300, 200)

    def show_window_2(self):
        self.w2 = Guitar_2()
        self.w2.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Guitar()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### **Второй код:**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication

class Guitar_2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setGeometry(250, 55, 1200, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Гитара')

        self.First_button = QPushButton('Первая струна(клавиша 1)', self)
        self.First_button.resize(170, 50)
        self.First_button.move(40, 100)

        self.Second_button = QPushButton('Вторая струна(клавиша 2)', self)
        self.Second_button.resize(170, 50)
        self.Second_button.move(40, 200)
```

---

*Также их можно объединить в один: просто перенесите `class Guitar_2(QWidget):` в первый код и уберите импорт этого класса, так как он больше не будет использоваться.*

Comment: @gil9red, внесите, пожалуйста, правки. Я приму их

Comment: Спасибо за отклик :) Кст, насчет переименования `Guitar_2`, чтобы при импорте не было конфликта из-за одинакового названия можно при импорте указать всевдоним, вот так: `from second_form import Guitar as Guitar_2`

Comment: а строка second_form import Guitar as Guitar_2 обязательна? Просто у меня и без неё работает

Comment: Если у вас все в одном коде, то будет и без нее работать. В принципе, можете убрать